# min value in array keeps printing 0? Java (but no zero in the .txt file as a number)

Tags: java

my code below works fine except for the minimum value. I cannot figure out why the min value keeps printing zero? The numbers in the .txt file its pulling from are: 2 6 9 35 2 1 8 8 4. It's as if its not recognizing that numbers[0] = 2. However max works fine and its the same code just reversed? Any help is appreciated.

```
import java.io.*;

import java.util.*;

class Thirteen{
   public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException{

      int count = 0;

      Scanner keys = new Scanner(System.in);
      Scanner keystwo;

      System.out.println("Please enter an input file name");
      String filename = keys.next();
      File infile = new File(filename);
      keystwo = new Scanner(infile);

      System.out.println("Please enter an output filename");
      String outputfile = keys.next();
      File outfile = new File(outputfile);

      FileOutputStream outstream = new FileOutputStream(outfile);
      PrintWriter display = new PrintWriter(outstream);


      while(keystwo.hasNext()){

         count++;
         int numbers [] = new int [count];
         int max = numbers[0];
         int min = numbers[0];
         int average = 0 ;
         int sum = 0;
         int counttwo = 0;

         while(keystwo.hasNext()){ 
            counttwo++;
            //add numbers to array
            for(int A = 0; A < numbers.length; A++){
               numbers[A] = keystwo.nextInt();
               sum = sum+ numbers[A]; 
               }
            // output numbers into txt file
            for(int item : numbers){
               display.println(item); 
               }
            for(int C: numbers){          
               if(C < min){
                  min = C;
                  }
               }   
            for(int B : numbers){
               if(B > max){
                  max = B;
                    }
                 }

            average = sum / counttwo;
      }//end while

      System.out.println("The total numbers in the array: " + counttwo ); 
      System.out.println("The maximum value is: " + max); 
      System.out.println("The minimum value is: " + min);
      System.out.println("The average value is: " + average);
      display.println("The total numbers in the array: " + counttwo ); 
      display.println("The maximum value is: " + max); 
      display.println("The minimum value is: " + min);
      display.println("The average value is: " + average);
      }//end first while

   keystwo.close();

   display.close();

   }
}//end
```

Comment: Why is the outer `while` loop a loop? When will it *ever* loop back, given that inner loop ensures that outer loop will never iterate a second time?

Answer (score 3):

It's because of your start value for min, which is going to be 0. Instead, set it to Integer.MAX_VALUE and you will get a proper min.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the minimum to 0:

```
min = numbers[0]; //numbers[0] is 0, since you haven't initialized it
```

You need to define the minimum as:

```
min = Integer.MAX_VALUE; //the largest possible value that int can have, so every other int is bigger
```

Also, it's advisable to do the same with your max. In this case it's not as important, but if you happen to have negative values in the `.txt` file, then `max` won't work either. To make sure that both minimum and maximum are correct, initialize the min as explained above, and the max to

```
max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```

Comment: Thanks, It only works reversed though. max = Integer.MIN_VALUE; min = Integer.MAX_VALUE; If i do it the other way i get the largest and smallest numbers used in java

Comment: @jeblacker yeah. oops :P my bad